# iOS application crashes during consecutive photo capturing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application, I am capturing five photos sequentially on a button click. But, when I press the home button in device in the midst of this photo shoot, as usual the app enters its background stage, but when I try to relaunch, the app crashes. Can you please suggest any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd look at what you're doing in viewDidLoad. If memory was cleared, viewDidLoad may be run again on relaunch. If you've set any delegates in viewDidLoad, they may no longer be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Hi please refer this three methods this may resolve your issue of memory leaks, actually crash is due to memory leaks because sometimes when we take more photos with high resolution and we are using it's our application then iphone is not capable of handle much more memory.

one more thing i need to say sorry because i don't know hoe to format code.

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
  {
  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [picker release];

  [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  [popover release];

  UIImage *capturedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
  [self performSelector:@selector(waitUntillImageCaptured:) withObject:capturedImage afterDelay:0.2];
  }

  -(void)waitUntillImageCaptured:(UIImage *)originalImage
  {
  UIImage *tempimg;

  tempimg = [self scaleAndRotateImage:originalImage];

  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSString *imagePath = [[appDelegate applicationDocumentDirectoryString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ClientTempthumb.png"];

  //UIImageView *tempView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tempimg];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempimg)];

  if(data != nil) 
  {
      [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
  }
  else
  {
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:NULL];
  }

  [btnPhoto setImage:tempimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [pool release];
  //    [appDelegate hideLoadingView];
  }

  - (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image {
    int kMaxResolution = 550; // Or whatever

  CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

  CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
  CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
  if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
      CGFloat ratio = width/height;

  ```
  if (ratio > 1) 
  {
      bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
      bounds.size.height = roundf(bounds.size.width / ratio);
  }
  else 
  {
      bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
      bounds.size.width = roundf(bounds.size.height * ratio);
  }
  ```

  }

  CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
  CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
  CGFloat boundHeight;
  UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;

  switch(orient) 
  {

  ```
  case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1

      // landscape right
      transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
      break;

  case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
      transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
      break;

  case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3

      // landscape left
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
      break;

  case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
      transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
      break;

  case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
      boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
      bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
      bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
      transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
      break;

  case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
      boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
      bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
      bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
      break;

  case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
      boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
      bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
      bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
      break;

  case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8

      // Portrait Mode 
      boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
      bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
      bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
      break;

  default:
      [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];
  ```

  }

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
      CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
      CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
  }
  else {
      CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
      CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
  }

  CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

  CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
  UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return imageCopy;
  }